# Why is the joint probability of a Bayesian Network multinomial?

Tags: probability-distributions, bayesian-network

As far as I know, the multinomial can be defined as:

Given a sequence of n independent trials each having identical probabilities
$p = (p_1, \ldots , p_k)$ for $k$ possible outcomes, the vector of the associated counts
$X = (X_1, \ldots ,X_k)$ is said to follow a multinomial distribution and it is denoted as $Mu(n, p)$.

In the context of bayesian networks,  we are interested in the joint probability distribution, say, for example, $p(X_1=A, X_2=B, \ldots, X_k=Z)$.

*Bayesian Networks in R with Applications in Systems Biology, by R. Nagarajan, M. Scutari and S. Lèbre*, says this is a Multinomial Distribution, Can someone explain why?

---

UPDATE: I post bellow the fragment where this is stated, in *Bayesian Networks in R with Applications in Systems Biology, by R. Nagarajan, M. Scutari and S. Lèbre, 2013, Springer (US)* (page $7$):

[image]

Comment: Nothing says that a Bayes net has to have a multinoimal distribution, or even a discrete valued one

Answer (score 0):

> Given a sequence of $n$ independent trials each having identical probabilities 
>   $\vec p=(p_1,\ldots,p_k)$ for $k$ possible outcomes, the vector of the associated counts $\vec X=(X_1,\ldots,X_k)$ is said to follow a multinomial distribution and it is denoted as $\mathcal{Mu}(n,\vec p)$.
>
> In the context of bayesian networks, ...

This has *nothing much* to do with Bayesian Networks in particular.

Are you conflating the term *multinomial* with *multivariate*?   They are not the same word.

A **multivariate distribution** is *any* joint probability distribution of multiple random variables.   That is all.   Bayesian Networks deal with multinomial distributions since they do concern the interrelation of multiple random variables.

A **multinomial distribution** is a rather *specific* familily of multinomial distribution; one where the random variables have a *particular* definition, as described below.   If you *do not* have this set up, then you *are not* dealing with a *multinomial* distribution.

---

> Can someone explain why this distribution is a Binomial one?

**Multinomial**.

The *Binomial Distribution* is a *special* case of the family: where $k=2$ (the two trial-outcomes of "fail" and "success"), then $\vec p=(1-p, p)$ and $X_1$ is the count for failures, and $X_2$ the count for successes in $n$ iid independent trials.

$$\mathsf P\big(\vec X=(n-x, x)\big)~=~ \dbinom {n}{x}(1-p)^{n-x}p^x\quad\mathbf 1_{x\in[0;n]\cap\Bbb Z}$$

Where $\binom n x$ is the count of distinct arrangements for $n$ trials consisting of $x$ successes and $n-x$ failures, and $(1-p)^{n-x}p^x$ is the probability for obtaining those results for each arrangment.

The *Multinomial Distribution* generalises this to a sequence of trials each resulting in exactly one from $k$ possible outcomes, and $\vec X$ is the multivariate vector of the counts for each of the $k$ outcomes occuring in $n$ such *independent and identically distributed* trials.

$$\mathsf P(\vec X=\vec x) ~{=~ \mathsf P(X_1=x_1, \ldots, X_k=x_k) \\ =~\binom{n}{x_1,\ldots,x_k} p_1^{x_1}\cdots p_k^{x_k}\quad\mathbf 1_{\vec x\in \Bbb N^k, \sum_{i=1}^n x_i=n}}$$

Where, $\dbinom{n}{x_1,\ldots,x_k}$ is called the *multinomial coefficient*, and equals $\dfrac{n!}{x_1!\cdots x_k!}$.  Hence the name.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, the title was correct, though. I don't get how this answer is supposed to help, I have already red the definition of the multinomial distribution, I just don't get why the joint distribution is a binomial one.  I do not see where are the $n$ trials in $p(X_1=A, X_2=B, \ldots, X_k=Z)$.

Comment: Each independent trial from the $n$ trials may result in one of $k$ types of outcomes.  For each outcome type-$i$ in $\{1,..,k\}$, we have $X_i$ as the count of outcomes of that type among the $n$ trials. @D1X

Comment: each trial may result in  all the combinations of the outcomes of each variable, for example for two binary variables $X_1, X_2$ there are four outcomes, not 2, $(1,1), (0,1), (1,0), (0,0)$. I understand p(X_1=A, X_2=B, \ldots, X_k=Z) as the probability of event A for $X_1$ and event $B$ for $X_2$ and so on, I only see one trial.

Comment: No. Each trial in a multinomial distribution results in exactly one from the possible outcomes. That is how it is defined.  Conversely, if that isn't the setup for the process, then you do not have a multinomial distribution.

Comment: PS: Are you confusing *multinomial* with *multivariate*?  Not all multivariate distributions are multinomial.

Comment: I still don't see it, sorry. If the BN has $2$ nodes $X_1$ and $X_2$. Let's suppose $X_1$ has two possible outcomes: $1$ and $2$ and that $X_2$ has $3$ possible outcomes: $1,2,3$. In this case, Joint Probability Distribution is defined as $P(X_1, X_2)$, and as far as I understand there is only one trial here. $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i= X_1+X_2$ is not $n$ (In this case $2$), indeed, $X_1+X_2$ can be $5$ if $X_1=2$ and $X_2=3$.

Comment: Yeap, @D1X , that is a *multivariate* joint distribution, **not** a *multinomial* one.

Comment: Then why is it said that the joint probability distribution of the nodes (Discrete Random Variables) of a Bayesian Network is a multinomial one.

Comment: It did not.  It said "Given a sequence of $n$ independent trials each having identical probabilities ..."   That is *not* what you are describing as a Bayesian Network.

Comment: I have updated the original post, Could you check it, please?

Comment: @D1X See, if you had done that in the first place we could have answered: It's wrong. The natural choice for a joint distribution of those variable is certainly *not* a multinomial distribution.

Comment: So... Any idea about where this confusion comes from? That book is one of the basics references for Bayesian Networks... Maybe it is due to the fact that a dataset that comes from a multivariate distribution can be considered drawn from a multivariate multinomial distribution?

Answer (score 0):

I think what the author of the book says is that since all 'nodes' of the network have a discrete number of states, you can represent the joint probability distribution as a multinomial distribution assigning a certain probability to each of the

3 x 2 x 2 x 2 x 2 x 3 = 144

combinations of the levels of the node variables. 
Thus you will have a

$P(\mbox{A='young', S='M', E='high', O='emp', R='small', T='car'}) = p_1$

$P(\mbox{A='adult', S='M', E='high', O='emp', R='small', T='car'}) = p_2$

$P(\mbox{A='old', S='M', E='high', O='emp', R='small', T='car'}) = p_3$

$P(...) = p_{144}$

which gives you 143 parameters (144 - 1 condition given by $\sum_i p_i=1$) to assign to describe such a multinomial.

I hope the answer is still useful despite the months that have passed since the question was formulated

Comment: No, that is not  Multinomial distribution. It is a categorical one, see the definition of Multinomial distribution posted by Graham Kemp.

Comment: You are right, of course. I had misread the previous reply and got convinced the problem was with the number of parameters :-(
Shall I edit my previous reply to rectify this important point or would it be a bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

The Joint Probability Distribution is not a Multinomial one. Seems like the author is wrong, since that is simply a categorical distribution with $144$ categories. As pointed out by **Graham Kemp** the (usual, because the author may be referring to another distribution) definition of the Multinomial Probability Distribution is as follows:

> The *Multinomial Distribution* generalizes this to a sequence of
>   trials each resulting in exactly one from $k$ possible outcomes, and
>   $\vec X$ is the multivariate vector of the counts for each of the $k$
>   outcomes occurring in $n$ such *independent and identically
>   distributed* trials.
>
> $$\mathsf P(\vec X=\vec x) ~{=~ \mathsf P(X_1=x_1, \ldots, X_k=x_k) \\
> > =~\binom{n}{x_1,\ldots,x_k} p_1^{x_1}\cdots p_k^{x_k}\quad\mathbf 1_{\vec x\in \Bbb N^k, \sum_{i=1}^n x_i=n}}$$
>
> Where, $\dbinom{n}{x_1,\ldots,x_k}$ is called the *multinomial
>   coefficient*, and equals $\dfrac{n!}{x_1!\cdots x_k!}$.

That being said, there is a Multinomial Distribution involved, and I think the author may be confusing at that paragraph the Joint Probability Distribution with **the distribution from which the dataset is drawn**. We can indeed consider the dataset to be a realization or sample from the Multinomial Distribution in which we have the vector of parameters $(p_1, ..., p_k)$ that characterize the probabilities of each variable and $N$ is the number of elements of the dataset.